# IQueryable LongTake and LongSkip methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Why there are no `LongTake` and `LongSkip` methods in IQueryable?

e.g. we have `LongCount` method

Which alternative code I should use for `LongTake` and `LongSkip` methods?

Comment: I think 2 billion+ is quite enough for take & skip methods, why do you need that?

Comment: That would depend completely on your query provider. The answer Noctis provides is valid for LINQ to Objects, but if (for example) you're querying a database provider, and you'd like to skip past 3 billion rows, it's not going to work. (Even where it does work, it's likely far too slow for actual use -- if you could skip past an element in a microsecond, which is very optimistic, you'd still need 36 minutes just to get past the first 2 billion elements.) That said -- when you want to skip billions of rows, there's probably something you're not doing right. Figure out a way to seek instead.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the fair comment by Alexander, which I asked myself as well, given that Skip is an extension method, and that you can see the code yourself, you can easily modify it and write your `LongSkip` yourself:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> LongSkip<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, long count) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return SkipIterator<TSource>(source, count);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, long count) {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (count > 0 && e.MoveNext()) count--;
            if (count <= 0) {
                while (e.MoveNext()) yield return e.Current;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will enumerate the "skipped" results too though, to be able to really do this on the database side, you'd need your own implementation of `IQueryProvider`

Comment: @AlexanderDerck there's a whole bunch of articles about why `Skip` is implemented that way, and even a skeet one on reimplementing linq i believe. You could also use an index if your source is `IList`, but if he wants to do that, he's welcome to. Even though I didn't answer the question of *why* isn't there, i gave him an option to have his own :).

Comment: I just think you're missing the point. You're talking about Linq to Object (and your answer is correct regarding that), but OP is talking about Linq to Entities